# Qt Quick Controls 2 TextArea `tabChangesFocus`, how to use Tab key to change focus, not type Tab character

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols2

QML `TextArea` from Qt Quick Controls 1.x (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html) had a property called `tabChangesFocus`, which could be set to toggle the behaviour of the Tab key between two possible actions:

- `true`: enter Tab character in the `TextArea`
- `false`: move the focus to next item in the tab Chain

This property doesn't seem to exist for `TextArea` in Quick Controls 2.x (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textarea.html).

The default is the `true` behaviour, but I would like the `false` behaviour (focus change).

Does anyone know a simple way to achieve the same effect for Quick Controls 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to use [`Item::nextItemInFocusChain()`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-item.html#nextItemInFocusChain-method). This way, you don't need to know the next item in focus chain:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Column {
        spacing: 20

        TextArea {
            id: textArea1
            focus: true
            text: "TextArea1"

            Keys.onTabPressed: nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus(Qt.TabFocusReason)
        }

        TextArea {
            id: textArea2
            text: "TextArea2"
            objectName: text

            Keys.onTabPressed: nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus(Qt.TabFocusReason)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should probably be made more convenient in the future, but you can setup tab navigation with [QML KeyNavigation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keynavigation.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Column {
        spacing: 20

        TextArea {
            id: textArea1
            focus: true
            text: "TextArea1"

            KeyNavigation.tab: textArea2
            KeyNavigation.backtab: textArea2
            KeyNavigation.priority: KeyNavigation.BeforeItem
        }

        TextArea {
            id: textArea2
            text: "TextArea2"

            KeyNavigation.tab: textArea1
            KeyNavigation.backtab: textArea1
            KeyNavigation.priority: KeyNavigation.BeforeItem
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is concise and works for me. Only short-coming is that each item needs to specify the id of the next in the tab-chain, and so it doesn't form a part of the built-in dynamic Qt Quick Controls 2 tab-chain. Having said that, this solution does what I need, so thank you. Also, the backtab is not necessary, because TextArea does not consume shift-tab key events, so that line could be omitted.

Comment: For reference, I have succesfully combined this with the accepted answer (bind to nextItemInFocusChain instead of explicit ids).
This is better as SHIFT+TAB is also supported.

Comment: `KeyNavigation.backtab: nextItemInFocusChain(false)
KeyNavigation.tab: nextItemInFocusChain(true)
KeyNavigation.priority: KeyNavigation.BeforeItem`